# Typescript transpile Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, typescript

Build details:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.4
Node: 15.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 11.2.3
typescript: 4.0.7
```

Currently I have the following imported:

`import * as ts from "typescript";`

and I have the following method:

```
 testingTranspile(){
    const sanitized: string= leadLocation.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.\[\]]/g, ""); 

    let code: string=`try{ console.log('works') } catch(e){ console.log(e.toString()) }  `; 
    let result = ts.transpile(code); 
    eval(result); 
 }
```

Which works, I do see the 'works' output on console when I `ng serve`

Now when I try to build the app however (via `ng build --prod --output-hashing none --extract-css`) I get the warning:

```
 Warning: ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 6116:41-60
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (...\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:40:18)    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1454:24)
    at ...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1258:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:53:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at ...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:672:17
    at _done (eval at create (...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at ...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1185:12
    at ...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1097:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11)
 @ ./src/app/component-library/test/test.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

The app does build, but I would like as much as possible to not have warnings.

I can tell it's the method above causing the problem because if I clear the contents of `testingTranspile()` we don't see the warnings on build anymore.

How can I resolve this warning? I tried looking for transpile/eval related warnings but could find none that fit this case.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this post because I also was getting:

```
"./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 3742:20-42
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"
```

Turns out my error was that I had a typescript import at the top of my file which wasn't being utilized anywhere. Not sure if you're having a similar situation, but just wanted to share - maybe try a lint test?

Comment: unfortunately no - in my code: ts.transpile(code) is using the import

Answer (score 2):

If you're using webpack, then it might be parsing the typescript.js file. Add the path to the typescript.js file causing the lint error in the `noParse` array, in your webpack.config.js file.

Add into webpack.config.js

```
const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",

  ...

  module: {
    rules: [...],
    noParse: [require.resolve("typescript/lib/typescript.js")],
  },

  ...

};
```

For NextJs add this into next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (
    config, options
  ) => {
    config.module.noParse = [require.resolve("typescript/lib/typescript.js")]
    return config
  },
};
```

This removes the lint warning in Vanilla js and Nextjs, I haven't tested for Angular.

Check out the [noParse Doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulenoparse).