# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression - nextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, configuration, i18next

I have a multi-language site using `i18next`. When I want to transition between pages it take too long for doing that and sometimes refresh the page.

I have this warning on console

```
warn  - ./node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I think problem is with my configuration.

`next.config.js`

```
const {i18n} = require('./next-i18next.config')
const withVideos = require('next-videos')
module.exports = withVideos({
  reactStrictMode : true,
  i18n,
  
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  },
})
```

`next-i18next.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    i18n:{
      locales: ['fa','en','ar'],
      defaultLocale: 'fa',
      localeDetection: false,
    },
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
  }
```

I used serverSideTranslations in code below

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, i18nConfig)),
    },
  };
}
export default function Home(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
.
.
.
return (
    <>
.
.
.
        {t("contact:helpDes")}
.
.
.
    </>
 )
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/1545. Your config files look fine. Can you show us where you're using `serverSideTranslations`?

Comment: hello, i updated first post and added serverSideTranslations part

Comment: check this answer, it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346797/9602452

Answer (score -3):

This may be due to the version of Next.js you are using. Try downgrading the version of Next.js to 12.2.2.